# Как передать данные из Активности во Фрагмент?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-intent, android-bundle

не получается передать данные из Активности во фрагмент
Пытаюсь сделать через `Bundle` - не выходит

```
    public class TranslateActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
    private static final int  NUM_PAGES = 5;
    private ViewPager TranslationPager;
    private PagerAdapter TranslationAdapter;



   String wordEnglish;
   String defenitionEnglish;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_translate);
//        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//        Intent intent = getIntent();
//        String Word = intent.getStringExtra("data");
//        bundle.putString("word", Word );


        ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
         pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

         Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b = getIntent().getExtras();
        wordEnglish = b.getString("wordEnglish");
        defenitionEnglish = b.getString("defenitionEnglish");
        Log.e("tryingtodosmth",wordEnglish);
        Log.e("tryingtodosmth2",defenitionEnglish);


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("wordEnglish2", wordEnglish);
        EnglishFragment english = new EnglishFragment();
        english.setArguments(bundle);


    }

}
```

Получение данных во фрагменте:

```
 public class EnglishFragment extends Fragment  {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private TextView  WordE;
    private TextView defEnglish;

    private String wordEnglish;


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public EnglishFragment() {

    }


    public static EnglishFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        EnglishFragment fragment = new EnglishFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {

        }

    }

//Получаю здесь данные
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_english, container, false);

        TextView WordE =v.findViewById(R.id.WordEnglish);
        TextView defEnglish = v.findViewById(R.id.BackgroundEnglish);
        String word = this.getArguments().getString("wordEnglish2");//Получаю 
                                                                     //данные
        Log.e("checkFrag",word)//Выкидывает исключение, что через log пытаюсь 
                               //вывести Null
        WordE.setText(word);//Ничего не сеттерит,(с закомменченым логом, 
                         //конечно), следовательно ничего не textview не 
                         //выводит, не считая hint'a, прописанного в XML


        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

   // @Override
   // public void onAttach(Context context) {
    //    super.onAttach(context);
   //     if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
      //      mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
      //  } else {
      //      throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
        //            + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
       // }
   // }


    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
}
```

Fragment PageAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private com.example.paulr.translaation_project.Second_Layout.EnglishFragment EnglishFragment;

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return EnglishFragment.newInstance("Hello world","Hi");
            case 1:
                return JapaniseFragment.newInstance("Hello world","Hi");
            case 2:
                return ChineseFragment.newInstance("Hello world","Hi");
            case 3:
                return RussianFragment.newInstance("Hello world","Hi");
                default: return EnglishFragment;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно передавать их в newInstance. Во фрагменте у вас уже создан заполненный метод в качестве образца. Просто приложите из активити параметры и все

Comment: Подозреваю, что Вы не тот экземпляр фрагмента выводите на экран, в который положили аргументы. Покажите весь кусок кода, где создаёте и добавляете фрагмент во `FragmentManager`. Или может фрагмент вообще прописан в макете активности?

Comment: @woesss сейчас добавлю

Comment: Лично у меня подозрения на `MyAdapter` падают. Вы пытаетесь что - то похожее написать? https://i.imgur.com/75zqnxN.png Если так, перепроверьте `getItem` или другой метод который у вас возвращает нужный `Fragment`. Было бы хорошо добавить этот адаптер на обозрение.

Comment: @KirstenLy сейчас

Comment: @KirstenLy добавил

Comment: По факту вы сохраняете строку `Hello world` с ключом `param1` и `Hi` с ключом `param2`. Так и доставайте их: `String word = getArguments().getString("param1")`.  Когда вы пишите `String word = this.getArguments().getString("wordEnglish2");` вы ищите строку с ключом `wordEnglish2`, и не находите её, потому что такого ключа в `Bundle` нет.

Comment: Так она же есть в 1 - ом классе, он передает Bundle, c этим ключом классу фрагмета, но не суть, как тогда изменить данные, которые он в switch'e  передает, допустим, я хочу, чтобы он первым аргументом передавал переменную wordEnglish из первого класса, как мне передать адаптеру переменную из активности?

Comment: Добавить её в конструктор адаптера, как вариант.

Comment: @KirstenLy, магия какая-то, до вас написал конструктор, он не работал, после вашего коммента все заработало